# Why am i getting permission denied in SCP for a local file as root?

Tags: unix, ssh, root, scp

I am trying to copy a file `f` I created on my local machine to a remote one (to the home directory of my user there) by SCP. I have root privileges on my machine, but after executing:

```
scp f username@remote.edu:/
```

I get:

```
scp: /f: Permission denied
```

Also

```
ls -l f
```

returns:

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

I'm confused, shouldn't i be able to copy it as root? Or even without it given the permissions?

Comment: I think that the error might be from remote host `remote.edu`. You may not have a permission to copy into `/`.

Comment: @sat wouldn't the error in that case be remote.edu:/ :permission denied? Also username@remote.edu:/ should be the home directory of the username i am logging onto? Can i not have permission to copy files there?

Comment: `username@remote.edu:/` doesn't mean that `username`s home directory. `/` means OS root directory. If you want to copy to `user` home directory,  you don't have to specify anthing, it will always copy to home directory. Or else you have specify `username:remote.edu:~/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is error from remote side saying that you don't have write access to the `/` of the `remote.edu`. I guess you don't want to copy the file to the `/`, but to the home directory:

```
scp f username@remote.edu:
```

SCP is a simple tool and does not have very advanced error reporting features and the messages might not be so straightforward as expected. But if you run the same command with `-vvv` switches, it should tell you more information what is going on behind the scenes and where the error is actually coming from.

Comment: You're right, the backslash was the problem, home is at username@remote.edu:. Cheers.

Comment: It is not backslash. It is normal (forward) slash meaning root of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this error, assign Read-write-execute (rwx) permission to everyone.

$ sudo chmod 777 "path-to-your-remote-directory"

Link : https://cloudlinuxtech.com/scp-permission-denied/